# Have a buffer show a "state mark"

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to to have a visible mark depicting the "state" the buffer is at.

A "state" is nothing more but a function that sets or unsets some keymapings that should be easily arbitrarily turned on or of on a per buffer basis.

I'm looking for a way to show some visual mark for every buffer that has that state set. Something like this (with ASCII graphics):

[image]

For example, pressing `F4` draw that little rectangle in the top, and repressing it clears it.

It doesn't have to be that exact visual mark, am open to suggestions that are simpler to implement but clearly show a visual difference in the buffer.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe add something to the status line. See `:help 'statusline'`.

Comment: Or you could keep it _really_ simple and make a subtle change to the background color or something. The other extreme would be to do something like what vim-airline does with it's "buffers" label in the top right corner when it's in buffer mode (not tab mode).

Answer (score 2):

> draw that little rectangle in the top

This will be possible when Neovim's ["floating windows" PR](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/6619) is merged.

Meanwhile you might be interested in `:help nvim_buf_set_virtual_text()`, it could be used to simulate a one-line floating status, but will require some logic to re-position the text when you scroll.

Try this:

```
:call nvim_buf_set_virtual_text(bufnr('%'), 0, line('w0')-1, [[repeat(' ',max([4,80-strdisplaywidth(getline(line('w0')))])).'Fancy Status', 'Error']],{})
```

- Re-execute the command (`@:`) whenever you move the viewport.
- Of course, a full solution will need to respond to cursor motion and remove the previous virtual text. Read `:help nvim_buf_set_virtual_text()`.